# How to 'mirror' a property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, innertext

I'm probably not using the correct term. What I want to achieve is to 'mirror' or 'sync' a variable in javascript. I have the following code:

```
class myClass {
    constructor(elem) {
        this.text = elem.innerText;
    }
}
```

This doesn't change the `innerText` property of `elem`. How would I configure the variable[s] to make them 'mirror' each other?

P.S I have had a hard time googling around on this one because I don't know the term for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: Look into AngularJS and similar bound templating systems. That code as is won't work, ever. You'll need some abstraction which can track changes and apply them.

Comment: Ugh. I'm building a lil' (standalone) library for manipulating the dom. I have a class that should have a text property.

Comment: @hiy: Notice that a "text *property*" works different than the `myVar` *variable* that your presented in your question, and (in contrast to variables) there are indeed solutions for making properties reflect others. You should [edit] your question to show your actual use case with the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myElem = Sizzle("#myElem");
var obj = {
    set myVar(text) {
        myElem.innerText = text;
    },
    get myVar() {
        return myElem.innerText;
    }
};
obj.myVar = "foo";
```

You can use [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) and [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), but you'll need your bound variable to be within an object.

**EDIT:**

Technically speaking, even global variables belong to the `window` object, so this should work:

```
var myElem = Sizzle("#myElem");
Object.defineProperty(window, 'myVar', {
    set: function(text) {
        myElem.innerText = text;
    },
    get: function() {
        return myElem.innerText;
    }
});
myVar = "foo";  // works assuming that we are using global scope
                // i.e. myVar isn't overridden in local scope
window.myVar = "foo"; // will work regardless
```

**UPDATE:**

Question was changed, so here is the updated answer:

```
class myClass {
    constructor(elem) {
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'text', {
            set: function(text) {
                elem.innerText = text;
            },
            get: function() {
                return elem.innerText;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: how would I use getters and setters on es6 classes?

Comment: Can you give context about the es6 class? It will depend on whether you want to do this in the constructor / methods, or if you want to do this to a particular object that is an instance of a class.

Comment: Sorry :-). I have a class with a constructor that takes an element as a parameter. In the constructor, `this.text` is set to the value of the parameter's innerText property. They should sync.

Comment: You can always use `Object.defineProperty` to define the getter and setter for an existing object.  In the case of es6 classes, said object would be the `this` object.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called data binding. Variables in Javascript do not inherently operate like this. You have to wrap them with getter/setter methods.

So it would look like something along these lines:

```
var myElem = Sizzle("#myElem");

mirror('myVar', function(myVar){
    myElem.innerText = myVar;
});

mirror('myVar', 'foo');
```

And the implimentation for mirror would look like this:

```
var __data__ = {};
var __bindings__ = {};
function mirror(name, value){
    // if no value is passed in
    // get the existing value
    if(!value){
        return __data__[name];
    }

    // if the "value" is a function
    // register it to the list of
    // functions that get called when
    // the value changes. Also known
    // as a listener.
    if(typeof value == 'function'){
        var func = value;

        // if there's no existing list
        // for this value, create one
        if(!__bindings__[name]){
            __bindings__ = [];
        }

        // if the data already exists
        // go ahead and fire this function
        // immediately
        if(__data__.hasOwnProperty(name)){
            func(__data__[name]);
        }

        __bindings__[name].push(func);
        return;
    }

    // if we've made it this far, we're setting
    // the value of our variable
    __data__[name] = value;

    // if there's a list of functions (listeners)
    // call each of them passing in the value that
    // we just set
    if(__bindings__.hasOwnProperty(name)){
        __bindings__[name].forEach(function(func){
            func(__data__[name]);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In js, just like in other program languages, assigning a primitive type variable, dose not create a reference to it.
so You would probably write this to set the innerHTML:

```
var myElem = Sizzle("#myElem");
myElem.innerText = "foo";
```

Comment: Many programming languages have the ability to make a variable be a pointer to something else.